# Switch Widget Inside RecyclerView Clickable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to use a Switch widget inside of a RecyclerView to set the particular component as active or not. How can I detect the switch toggling from the RecyclerView? My current OnItemClickListener intercepts the click on the Switch widget also.

Current Click Listener Code:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
        new RecyclerItemListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecyclerView,
                new RecyclerItemListener.RecyclerTouchListener() {
                    public void onClickItem(View v, int position) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked, position " + position + ". Name: " + GlobalData.totalAlarms.get(position).getAlarmName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                    public void onLongClickItem(View v, int position) {
                    }
                }));
}
```

Layout for RecyclerView, including Switch:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_mainactivityName"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_mainactivityTime"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_mainactivityDays"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_mainactivityTime"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_mainactivityName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_mainactivityActive"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/recycler_mainactivityTime"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recycler_mainactivityTime"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I remove the addOnItemTouchListener, the switches do toggle on click rather than being forced to swype.. Beyond that, how can I detect the touch? The addOnItemClickListener seems to intercept all clicks (unless I do a long click, then the switches toggle).

Answer (score 0):

Add a OnCheckChangeListener of the switch inside your recyclerView adapter to get the state of the switch

Comment: That works, but when I click on the Switch nothing happens.. I have to either long press for it to switch or drag it.. If I just tap it like normal, the RecyclerView click takes over.

Comment: I believe it has something to do with how I intercept the RecyclerView clicks, but not sure of any other way.. Tried MotionEvent, but that didn't work.